# Catch Exception (InputMissmatch) and want to re-enter input again

Tags: java, exception

here is my code where i want to re-enter input if any miss match exception happens

its date taking program where user can input date and its going to check it is valid date or not .

```
import java.util.*;

public class P3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int day=0,month=0,year=0;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int count=1;
        do {
        System.out.println("===============================\n===============================");
        
        System.out.println("Enter (DD-MM-YYYY)");
        
        try {   
        
         //day Part 
         System.out.print(" DD: ");
         day=sc.nextInt();
         if(day<1||day>31) {
                System.out.println("invalid day [range:1-31]\nEnter Again");
                continue;
            }
         
         //Month Part
         System.out.print(" MM: ");
         month=sc.nextInt();
         if(month<1||month>12) {
                System.out.println("invalid month [range:1-12]\nEnter Again");
                continue;
            }        
         //Year part
         System.out.print(" YYYY: ");
         year=sc.nextInt();
         if(year<1900) {
        System.out.println("no support for year less then 1900 [range:1900-current]");
                System.exit(0);
            }
         
         System.out.println("Day: "+day+" Month: "+month+" year: "+year);
         System.out.println("===============================\n===============================");
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("you enter wrong Input");
            sc.next();
        }
            
        --count;
        }while(count>0);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

this is my catch block in above program i cant perform the re-input if exception happens please help me with this.

Comment: `System.out.println("you enter wrong Input");sc.next();` --> `System.out.println("you enter wrong Input"); continue;`

Comment: yes its works now thanks , can you explain a bit how its functioning? where i did wrong?

Comment: continue skips the rest of the execution, and goes to the next iteration (of any while/do-while/for loop) because of this, it skips `--count;` so count remains 1, `count>0` evaluates to true

Comment: @experimentunit1998X thanks for your valuable reply.